# using EasyNetQ multiple Handler for one consumer does not work

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, consumer, easynetq

We are using RabbitMQ for queuing messages in C# .Net (EasyNetQ Client).

i want one consumer app (C# Console App) listen to one queue and provide multiple handlers for each message type.

I implemented this scenario and my code is here :

```
using (var advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;prefetchcount=100")
                                    .Advanced)
{
    var queue = advancedBus.QueueDeclare("MyQueue");

    advancedBus.Consume(queue, x => x
               .Add<MessageType1>((message, info) =>
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("MessageType1 Body : " + message.Body.Body);
               })
               .Add<MessageType2>((message, info) => 
               {
                  Console.WriteLine(" MessageType2 Body: " + message.Body.Body);
               }).ThrowOnNoMatchingHandler = false);
}
```

**My Problem :
But when i execute this consumer it does nothing. do not any thing happen.**

i publish messages to that queue like this :

```
using (var advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost").Advanced)
{
    var queue = advancedBus.QueueDeclare("MyQueue");

    if (advancedBus.IsConnected)
        advancedBus.Publish(Exchange.GetDefault(), queue.Name, false, false,
            new Message<MessageType1>(change));
    else
        result = false;
}
```

What is the problem.

Comment: Does `advancedBus.IsConnected` fall through? Are you able to connect to rabbit at all?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Yes. it's connected. when i Subscribe to specific message type it works perfect, but in my a bow scenario it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after testing this code, these are the problems:

First of all, you're disposing your `advancedBus` right after you register for consumption. You need to remember that when you invoke `IAdvanceBus.Consume`, ***you're only registering a callback*** for each message. If you dispose the bus immediately after registration, your delegate can't be invoked since the connection was already closed. So, you'll to remove the `using` statement around the rabbit declaration (don't forget to dispose it when you're done):

```
var advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;prefetchcount=100").Advanced
```

Second, the `immediate` flag [has been deprecated and shouldn't be used](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/), the message doesn't seem to be getting to the queue. Change `Publish` to:

```
advancedBus.Publish(Exchange.GetDefault(), queue.Name, true, false,
                    new Message<MessageType1>(change));
```

Also, if you're running this from a console application, don't forget to use `Console.ReadKey` so your main thread doesn't terminate.

Here's a working code sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    var change = new MessageType1();
    var advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost").Advanced;

    ConsumeMessage(advancedBus);

    var queue = advancedBus.QueueDeclare("MyQueue");
    if (advancedBus.IsConnected)
    {
        advancedBus.Publish(Exchange.GetDefault(), queue.Name, true, false,
            new Message<MessageType1>(change));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't connect");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void ConsumeMessage(IAdvancedBus advancedBus)
{
    var queue = advancedBus.QueueDeclare("MyQueue");
    advancedBus.Consume(queue, registration =>
    {
        registration.Add<MessageType1>((message, info) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", message.Body);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear Yuval, it solved my problem. Disposing was my problem.